# TFS 2010 and Setting up alerts for the team?

Tags: tfs-2010

What is the best way to have one admin setup alerts for the entire team. Especially those users who may not be using VS2010? I have read about the command line tool: BisSubscribe.exe, but is there an easier tool for command line novices? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TFS web interface is pretty decent for setting up alerts.  No Visual Studio required.

To add alerts via Team System Web Access:

- Open the Settings dropdown (far right side of screen).
- Choose Team Project | Alerts
- Custom Alert Subscription (halfway down the page).  From there you can setup what kind of alert and who it should go to.

Comment: But is there a way for me to subscribe user's to alerts?

Answer (score 2):

Also, check this:
http://tfseventhandler.codeplex.com/

and this:

http://blog.hinshelwood.com/team-foundation-server-2010-event-handling-with-subscribers

Comment: good find thanks...i had searched high and low for something like this!